# How to chose image dimensions on a background:cover div?

Tags: css, web, slider

I have a slider on my page with the property background cover applied so it fits the whole thing. The slider also has a 50vh fixed height.

The background always ends up cutting things from the image that I don't want.

How should I go about choosing the right width x height knowing that the website will be seen in very different devices?

Comment: please share code of slider

Answer (score 0):

The only other options besides cover are "contain" which scales the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area, thus leaving uncovered areas in the div's background.  The other option is setting it to "100% 100%" which will stretch the image, and distort it in odd sizes.

Pick your poison ;-)

Comment: Or you can spice it up with some hard core javascript, in that case, it would be needed to use an absolutely positioned image, where you calculate the area of the things you need to show and then calculate the position from that and viewport size...